# How to append api key to my url?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have successfully generated the api key by particular user using django-tastypie. Please see below code,

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        authorization = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        resource_name = 'user'
```

I try to access the json data using `http://10.90.90.95:3000/api/v1/user/?username=ravi&api_key=66184ad5abfbda8fcd1688c9e8a3780842262658gdf&format=json`.It gives the following traceback.

`line 590, in authorized_read_list auth_result = self._meta.authorization.read_list(object_list, bundle) AttributeError: 'ApiKeyAuthentication' object has no attribute 'read_list'`.

Please solve my problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just came across this same error, and it's because you've mixed up authentication with authorization. So, it should read:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'user'
```